# How to use CheckComboBox in editable table cell? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I know regular ComboBoxes can be used in TableView cells and be editable as per http://o7planning.org/en/11079/javafx-tableview-tutorial. However I would like to do the same with CheckComboBox from ControlFX, but I can't figure out how. I found this class called [CheckComboBoxTableCell](https://github.com/iMoHax/Trader/blob/master/client/src/main/java/ru/trader/view/support/cells/CheckComboBoxTableCell.java) but I get stuck on how to use the forTableColumn() method. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to use the CheckComboBoxTableCell in your link and wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: Maybe someone would be willing to contribute one to ControlsFX.